# Add new line using awk, sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a large file which is slightly corrupted. The new lines have disappeared. There should have been a new line at every 250th character. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
sed 's/.\{250\}/&\n/g'
```

The `.\{250\}` captures 250 of any type of character. The characters are replaced by themselves, plus a newline.

Comment: Works fine, much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sed -r 's/.{250}/&\n/g'
```

**gawk**:

```
awk -v FPAT='.{1,25}' -v OFS='\n' '$1=$1'
```

Comment: It should be noted that `FPAT` need v.4x to work.  Not installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 and if I remember correctly nor 13.04

Comment: @Jotne yep. gawk 4.0+. I don't use ubuntu since 8.04,  don't know about the default installed version. But you can install things by your own. (I installed 4.1.0)

Answer (score 4):

There is a command in `coreutils` that can wrap lines, it is called `fold`:

```
fold -w 250
```

Comment: +1 for using `fold`, but your description (understanding?) of `-b` isn't quite correct.

Comment: @devnull: You are right, I read the info page too quickly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^.\{250\}/&\
/;P;D' YourFile
```

Could be faster on huge file

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` version

```
awk '{L=250;for (i=1;i<=length($0);i+=L) print substr($0,i,L)}'
```